# NSTokenField set maximal number of Token

Tags: cocoa, nstokenfield

Let's say, I have a TokenField, where the user can input who the message should be sent to.
But I don't want that the user can input more than 3 Token.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Limit the Number of Tokens in a NSTokenField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649986/how-to-limit-the-number-of-tokens-in-a-nstokenfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `NSTokenField` Delegate  `tokenField:shouldAddObjects:atIndex:`

```
// return an array of represented objects you want to add.
// If you want to reject the add, return an empty array.

- (NSArray *)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField shouldAddObjects:(NSArray *)tokens atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (index>2) {
        return [NSArray array];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@-- %d %d", tokens, [tokens count],index);
    return tokens;
}
```

Comment: [for documentation purpose] The answer is wrong, "index" is not the total number of tokens in the tokenfield but the insertion position for the new token, using this approach you can add how many token you want but only if you move your cursor in the 1th or 2th position.